# EDI AS2 certificate from a trusted authority

Tags: certificate, biztalk, edi, smime

We need to setup an EDI AS2 connection with a trading partner who doesn't accept self signed certificates. As far as I know AS2 uses S/MIME certificates also known as email certificates, right?

I assume all I need is to buy an email certificate from a trusted authority like SwissSign or Digicert. But I wasn't able to find any related product to AS2. Furthermore I'm confused if buying an email certificate is the right way, because in EDI AS2 communication there is no email address.

Has anyone experience with this and can point me to the right product/certificate to buy?

Comment: It isn't an "email certificate" it is an X.509 certificate that you use to sign your messages with.  It is the same as a certificate that you use for SSL

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an "email certificate" it is an X.509 certificate that you use to sign your messages with.  I think you got confused because it mentioned MIME, which is used in email, but isn't exclusive to that.  It is the same as a certificate that you can use for SSL, but with AS2 people usually don't worry about getting a CA one, as it is cheaper to self generate and send your trading partners the public key so they can verify you as the sender.

See [AS2: Part 3 – Certificates](https://www.ld.com/as2-part-3-certificates/)

> With AS2 we do not need a CA to trust the authenticity of the other party, because we have already secured its public certificate through another channel. This means it is a waste of time and money to get your AS2 public certificate signed by a CA.

Possibly if you company already has a certificate used for a web site of your company, you could potentially just use that for your AS2 as well.